# Could load file or assembly XXX.dll when deploying sub application in iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I am using Dynamics CRM. in iis Under the Dynamics deployment , I am adding WCF sub-application (right click add app).

I am getting the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Crm, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

But when I deploy it independently, it works fine, with no errors.
The app pools contains is the same configuration. same version, same mod.
I am deploying sub application to overcome cross domain js problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A sub application in IIS picks up web.config of parent website as well. 
If Microsoft.Crm is needed for the parent website application and not for sub application, you could add a location tag around the parent-website specific configurations.

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
<connectionStrings>
....
</connectionStrings>
</location>
```

Another option is add these dlls to your sub application (not recommended).